# Computer stops working after 5 minutes of use in windows

Tags: power-supply, crash, shutdown, desktop-computer

I recently bought a PC in parts. I installed Windows 10 on it and it worked flawlessly for about a week and a half. However, now it turns off whenever I'm doing something, even if it's not a heavy software like a video game. I think this issue may be related to the power source. I need some guiding to know if indeed I need to change this part or if it may be another issue causing the crash.

My computer components are:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- MSI X570 gaming plus motherboard
- AMD RX580 graphic card
- 8gb x 2 corsair ddr4 300MHz Ram
- HDD Toshiba 1.5TB
- SSD PNY 960GB
- PCIe WiFi card
- Power source : Corsair Vs650W 80+

Please help me. I spent a lot of money on this computer and I really need it to work properly.

Comment: Did you check the CPU temperature? If it's too high, the computer will turn off. So check if the CPU is correctly mounted with (thermal) silver paste. This may be a reason for overheating.

Comment: If not temperatures then the next most likely contributors could be PSU or the Motherboard. I had a similar issue with my relatively old Windows 7 Desktop. After 10 - 15 minutes it would just abruptly shut down.Fortunately I had a spare PSU to test and when I replaced the PSU with my spare one, it worked fine for hours.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases a PC shutting down by itself is due to CPU temperatures (Not always, but often)

I'd suggest downloading [HW Monitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) or [CoreTemp](https://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) to check your CPU temperatures. If they're reasonable (20 below throttle), you can use the [Prime95](https://www.mersenne.org/download/) utility to stress test your cpu, and see if the temperatures go overboard

If not, you will need to test your components individually (As in, removing a RAM, doing your tests, trying another RAM slot, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure heat sinks and thermal paste are properly implemented (noted above). Make sure fans are running correctly (all fans). Make sure the surrounding air is not too hot (in a computer cupboard for example).

Make sure power supply voltages are correct for your computer.

Make sure power supply and motherboard are properly grounded at the proper tie points in the case. I have seen this cause issues.

Make sure all drivers are fully up to date and you have the newest BIOS installed.