# Can a PSU start failing a week after installation with the same components to supply

Tags: power-supply, crash, desktop-computer

I recently bought a desktop computer in parts. It worked nice for about a week and then it started rebooting weirdly. 
I tried reinstalling the system but the problem persists. Is it possible that the PSU stopped working properly even though it did work for a week with the same components?

This is my set up :

MSI MPG X570
AMD RYZEN 5 3600
AMD RX580
2x8 GB corsair vengeance ddr4
1 SSD, 1 HDD
Pcie WiFi card

PSU: Corsair VS650

Please, I need to fix this problem I have spent a lot of money on it.

Comment: Check the stated power consumption (in datasheets!) for all the components, sum it up to an *estimated* highest plausible number; verify that the PSU is capable of delivering that - with some margin (I'd say 50% extra). Continuously!

Comment: Do you know what "ESD" is; did you use an earthing wristband while handling the components? e.g. https://www.amazon.com/earthing-bracelet/s?k=earthing+bracelet

Comment: It's always possible for any part of your PC to fail but nothing you said in the post would cause me to think it was the PSU above any other part. With the information you gave us there is no way to know why your PC is failing. Are there any error messages? What happens right before it fails (if you notice any pattern)? When it turns on, does it work like normal? Does window enter any auto-recovery modes? Etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computer stops working after 5 minutes of use in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1521489/computer-stops-working-after-5-minutes-of-use-in-windows)

Comment: Could you explain what is different between this question and your original one?

Answer (score 4):

It’s much more likely to fail after a week than after six months. It’s called the [bathtub curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve) — failures are more likely at both the beginning and end of a component’s life.

Comment: Mike's right. Hardware generally fails early if it's gonna fail.

Answer (score 2):

You might check with Corsair Support. It could have a failing or intermittent part. Mean time to failure is just an average and electronic components can fail quickly or last for years.  Check your other components as well